Is there current from Vin in this ideal op-amp circuit?
Before we start: yes, I already know the there is no current flowing into the inverting or non-inverting terminals of an ideal op-amp, and that the node between R1 and R3 is 0 V.
The Question:

Professor's Solution:


My Solution:


My Reasoning:
I believe current flows from Vin to the Vee rail of the op-amp or from Vcc rail of the op-amp to Vin.


Professor's Reasoning:
The professor believes there is no current flowing from Vin and there is only a voltage imposed there and there are two currents flowing out from Vin Node (the green one and the yellow one) and they loop around.

My Response:

If I am wrong, can someone please explain? I might have to relearn everything I know about op-amps as well as transistors (especially push and pull pairs) and my final exam is close by.

You are beating this thing to death. You already have opinions from the prior question. Your formulation for Vout is correct. And the value of I1 is not zero. That's obvious as R1 is connected to a virtual ground. So end of story. You only need to find a different professor. Which we can't help with. And I still think you have a bad practice naming resistors with the same identifier for no more reason than that you, a priori, know they have the same value.

Are you using the 741 opamp as some sort of ideal model here?

@pipe The title says it.

@periblepsis Please explain, did you just change the title and it has not updated yet? I see no mention of the 741 in the title.

@pipe The title says "ideal opamp". That's what I meant. So it's not a 741.

@periblepsis I am sorry but the resistor naming convention is done by the university, not me, to optimize it for Mathematica.

@MikeWazowski Still is bad practice. So I guess it's both a bad professor AND a bad practice. You still have the right of it, too. So you are fine.

@pipe I removed the tag for 741. Sorry for the confusion.

@MikeWazowski I won't be writing another answer for you. You don't like brute force methods, it seems. But it is easy to "brute force" this to make the solid case, if that's all you care about. To do that, use the brute force method and insert a 0 V voltage supply between Vin and the rest of the circuit. Solve again for the current through that 0 V voltage source. Don't ask me to help further. But you are right that the input current isn't zero. And you have the right Vout equation.

Will do that. Thank you very much. I will use the answer you gave previously in the other thread as well.

Stop beating the professor about one silly little mistake in a basic circuit. Making one mistake doesn't mean it's a bad professor. Depending on your university, it may not even be the professor that teaches the basic courses, or prepares the material what to teach. They rarely deal with mundane things like basic electronics courses anyway. So it's a mistake anyone could have made. Now, making the professor to see the mistake and admit it can be harder, due to the reasons I mentioned. The professor may have a good reason to believe and expect that the teaching material is flawless.

@Justme This is just a small part of a bigger problem we are having here. The professor said they will not be checking our solutions during the final exam and that their given answer is final. So if we don't get the exact same answer as the professor, we get zero marks. I am pointing out all the mistakes made by the professor in practice problems in the hope that they realise they can make mistakes too and will consider checking our workings during the final exam if we do not get exactly the same answer as the professor.

@All - We're getting flags that comments have drifted off-topic. Although the OP has just added some useful context about why they are asking these questions, let's avoid going further into the OP's classroom situation, as that is off-topic here. Please limit this to the on-topic electronics questions now. TY (Either Academia.SE or Interpersonalskills.SE might be appropriate places for follow-up questions, depending on whether the desired outcome is to change the course marking rubric or to have better communications with the professor.)

I think I agree with you, here are my thoughts:
There's no current in R5, due to infinite input impedance of the op-amp, so R5 and everything to the right can be disregarded, in the context of your question.
By op-amp action, the junction of R1 and R3 is 0V. Treating the op-amp as a voltage source \$V_1\$, what remains is this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With the same potential difference across the pair R1 & R3 as there is across the pair R2 & R4, right off the bat it's clear that \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ have the same sign, and with nowhere else for current to flow, there's only one condition that yields \$I_0 = I_1 + I_2 = 0\$; when \$I_1=0\$, which can only occur if \$V_1 = V_{IN}\$.
The claim that \$I_0\$ is always zero is not correct, but just to be certain, we should determine the relationship between \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_1\$. For the chain consisting of R1 and R3, these are the current equations:
$$ I_1 = \frac{V_{IN} - 0}{R_1} $$
$$ I_1 = \frac{0 - V_1}{R_3} $$
Equating those, we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{V_{IN} - 0}{R_1} &= \frac{0 - V_1}{R_3} \\ \\
V_1 &= -V_{IN}\frac{R_3}{R_1} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
That's just what you'd expect from an inverting amplifier, as is the case, becoming clearer if I redraw that section like this:

simulate this circuit
So, given that the only occasion when \$V_{IN} = V_1\$ (the condition necessary for \$I_0=I_1+I_2=0\$), this can only occur when \$V_{IN} = V_1 = 0\$.

Oh, and just to preserve your self-confidence, you are also correct when you infer that the op-amp output must be sinking current to \$V_{EE}\$ or sourcing current from \$V_{CC}\$, depending on whether \$V_1 < V_{IN}\$ or \$V_1 > V_{IN}\$ (respectively).

Thank you so much for your input. I appreciate it a lot. I have never thought of treating the opamp as a voltage source to simply calculations.

@MikeWazowski It's this easy. You really need to dump the professor.

@MikeWazowski you're welcome. Good luck with the exams. Knock it out of the park, brother.

@periblepsis If it was easy to dump one's prof, then problem solved! Few have that luxury, though. Besides, this is what we are here for, partly at least.

I accidentally I ended up learning more about circuit analysis from the unique ways you all approach circuit analysis for the same question, than all my lecture videos.

@MikeWazowski What I learned from colleagues in my first year in the field following university was priceless. I'm not saying what I learned at university wasn't important, but those guys in the labs, wow, best teachers around, some of them.

@SimonFitch This question about the current is a two resistor problem. Full stop. If the professor cannot handle this, then the further risks of harm done by sitting in class any further is frightening. So, if the professor persists I would bail the class, make an appointment with the department chair for a discussion, and not take any further classes from that individual and, depending on the department chair meeting, perhaps any classes from that department. (I've already had such a department chair meeting just two years ago after having sat a 2nd year class, watching.)

Yes, there is obviously a current through Vin.
Here is my little "contribution" ...
From "professor's solution" picture, equations are not 'right'.
With one example of value resistor's.


I don't like brute force (KCL) solutions to problems like this, as they obscure the logic behind the obvious.
Vin is an input to the problem, so you can regard it as a voltage source. It obviously has a current flowing out of it, it has resistors connected to it for goodness sake. It will supply whatever current the resistors demand, without changing its voltage.
The first op-amp and R1&R3 form an inverting amplifier with gain -R3/R1, and so output voltage -Vin.R3/R1. This is also zero output impedance, due to the ideal op-amp operation.
As there is no current into the second op-amp's noninverting input, R5 might as well not be there, and does not load the R2&R4 potential divider. As that potential divider is driven from two voltage sources and is unloaded, only the values of R2 and R4 are needed to write its output voltage as a function of its input voltages Vin and -Vin.R3/R1 - I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.
The second op-amp is a noninverting gain stage controlled by R5&R6, which amplifies the voltage at its noninverting input, again a trivial equation to write down.

Tbh, I never knew such circuit analysis methods existed before I came onto Stack Exchange. I always thought KCL was the only proper way. Now circuits make more sense to me.

'proper' depends on context. If you are solving a circuit by hand, then it makes sense to carve it into isolated sub-circuits as far as possible (those zero impedance points driving R2/4 isolate R1/3 from R2/4) whose gains or voltages can be written down 'by inspection'. If doing a computer solve, then plugging everything into a vast equation and turning the handle will get you the answer, but little understanding, and ONLY if you haven't lost track of a stray minus sign or two, which you will never find in that forest of algebra. My - sign hygiene is appalling, so I avoid the latter.

@MikeWazowski Actually now reading your question properly (I never wade through forests of algebra, simply solve the circuit by inspection), your Prof's very first equation KCL at Vin is wrong. It has to be understood that the schematic assumes that Vin is driven by something off-sheet that can supply current, so it's a category error to even try to do KCL at that node.

@MikeWazowski There are several stages to analysing a circuit. First the ideal circuit, using human heuristics to understand it, break it into isolated comprehensible chunks. Second, the detailed behaviour. Op-amp output impedance is not zero, especially at high frequencies, so do you include it in KCL? No, you slap it into a simulator, which takes care of all the other non-idealities, to show you the small deviations you get from ideal. Third you build it, to discover what important real world things have been left out of the simulator model.

I am currently designing a circuit for my mini project but I started off with calculating everything in their non-ideal equations, meaning for transistors for example, I don't exclude the effects of thermal voltage and reverse saturation current or the un-ideality factor.  Is this what you would consider the First Ideal Circuit stage? Or have I already compensated for most of the un-ideal factors, bar parasitic capacitances and inductances as well as manufacturing tolerances which I believe I can compensate for with an extra opamp stage.

As you already noticed, the current through \$R_1\$ is easy, for \$R_2\$ we first need the output of the left opamp, \$V_1\$ in the second picture from the top. Then:
$$\begin{align}
I(R_1)&=V_\text{in}/R_1
\\[5pt]
V_1&=-\frac{R_3}{R_1} \ V_\text{in}
 \\[5pt]
 I(R_2)&=\frac{V_\text{in}-V_1}{R_2+R_4}
 = \frac{R_1+R_3}{R_1(R_2+R_4)}\ \ V_\text{in}
\\[5pt]
 I_\text{in} =I(R_1)+I(R_2)&=
\frac{R_1+R_2+R_3+R_4}{R_1(R_2+R_4)}\ \ V_\text{in}
\end{align}$$

Thank you again for your input
